# Spinner style (AppCompat Light DarkActionBar) for a button => wrong icon color

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-appcompat, material-design

I use a theme bases on `AppCompat.Light.DarkActinBar`.

**(1) Spinner works as expected**

If I add a spinner like following, everything works as expected:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And set the adapter:

```
adapterType = new ArrayAdapter<MappedResourceValue>(getActivity(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, statisticTypes.getValues());
adapterType.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spType.setAdapter(adapterType);
```

**(2) Spinner style for a view does not work**

If I add a button and want to style it, it does look like a spinner, but it has a WHITE drop down icon instead of a dark one...

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btTypes"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I also tried `style="?android:spinnerStyle"` which apperently does not make any difference...